# Boost.Asio: Does several async_recv_until() calls finish and have their callbacks in order of method invocation?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

> Boost.Asio: Does several async_recv_until() calls finish and have their callbacks in order of method invocation?

I have a program that could make two `async_recv_until()` calls before the server will reply.

However, it is crucial, that the first call `async_recv_until()` gets this reply. Is there any way to ensure this?

Comment: If both calls are against the same socket, the callbacks will occur in the posted order (unless some underlying error causes one to callback early).  Though having state that is dependent on the ordering of these calls seems like a flawed design decision.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have typo: there is no `async_recv*` operations in asio api. There is `async_read*` and `async_receive`, which is slightly different behavior.

You cannot queue `async_read*` operations on same socket (but you can do them on different sockets, one active at a time for each socket). From [async_read docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html):

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read
>   operations (such as async_read, the stream's async_read_some function,
>   or any other composed operations that perform reads) until this
>   operation completes.

So the answer is: you should do your second `async_read_until` only after first finishes (after callback is called).